# Pass current element + other argument to .every callback function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that checks if an element contains at least N characters. This function takes 2 arguments: the element and the minimum number of characters.

```
validateDescription = (input, car) => {
  descriptionInputLength = input.value.replace(/\s/g, "").length;
  valid = descriptionInputLength >= car;
  return valid;
};
```

I want to execute this function on all the elements of an array using `.every` but I don't know how to pass the arguments correctly given that it function is called as a callback.

I tried the following, which obviously is not correct (element not defined), but I'm struggling to figure out how to make it work.

```
exampleArray.every(validateDescription(element, 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) needs function, or reference to function as an argument. But you are passing boolean (`validateDescription()` returns boolean)

So, what you need is:

```
exampleArray.every(element => validateDescription(element, 10))
```

or

```
exampleArray.every(function(element) { return validateDescription(element, 10)})
```

or

```
function check(element) {
       return validateDescription(element, 10)
}

exampleArray.every(check)
```